# Kohana sessions with Https

Tags: session, https, kohana

I have a a main controller that checks if session security is set and If not it will redirect to secure controller.

The problem is the secure controller is through https, it checks password and sets the session and redirects to main controller. I cant access the session set through https in http.

How do I use https and redirect to normal http then? I need the sessions in http and https

Anyideas?

> **EDIT**

OK, I checked around and it is not realy possible without keeping things secure. 
One option is to have the session sent over GET but its obviously insecure, So what if after checking login I redirect them to a https form that posts the session to a normal http page, at the html page i check the headers and make sure it came from my https page.
Does that sound secure to you??

Answer (score 0):

Make your entire app HTTPS. Attached is the block I use for almost all my sites, redirecting everything on 80 to 443.

```
##
# Sample config for a site needing SSL
#

$HTTP["host"] =~ "^ssl_example.localhost(:[0-9]+)?$" {
    # Serve everything over HTTPS
    $SERVER["socket"] == ":80" {
        url.redirect-code = 301
        url.redirect = ( "/(.*)" => "https://ssl_example.localhost:%1/$1" )
    }

    # This would be a great place to test SSL config for QA/Dev zones...
    $SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {
        ssl.engine = "enable"
        ssl.pemfile = rootdir + "/etc/ssl/example.pem" 
        server.document-root = "/home/crosslight/ssl_example/default"
        accesslog.filename = rootdir + "/var/log/ssl_example.log"
        server.errorlog = rootdir + "/var/log/ssl_example.error.log"
        server.tag = "Crosslight (lighttpd-1.4.28 + php-5.3.3) / SSL"

        // CodeIgniter/Kohana rewrite rules
        url.rewrite-once = (
            "^/index\.php" => "/index.php", #truncate index.php?params to just index.php
            #### Serve static content
            "^/(static.*)" => "/$1",
            "^/(blog.*)" => "/$1",
            "^/(.*)$" => "/index.php/$1"
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make your whole page part of the secure site (https)?  I don't see a way to do the http => https conversion without passing the GET key between sites.

I don't think it's such a huge security concern if your logic is to take the session id (only the key) from a cookie on the http side of the house and make it a cookie (manually) on the https side of the house.  You can then perform your normal session handling validation to see if it is a valid session.  Isolates your logic from abuse as much as possible.

In the backend, you can share the session information between the sites or you can trigger a copy from the http to https based on the session id retrieved.  Depends on your architecture.